# AWS Elastic Beanstalk ACM SSL certificate installation without load balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ruby-on-rails, elastic-beanstalk

Reading through the AWS docs just now, it appears that:

1. I can get a free SSL/TLS certificate from Amazon for use with certain AWS services. This is facilitated via the ACM (AWS Certificate Manager) console: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html.
2. Elastic Beanstalk is now one of the services which can use the ACM certificate obtained above.
3. The recommended way to install the certificate is to apply it to the load balancer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html.
4. In cases where you don't have a load balancer in your EB environment, it is possible to instead install the certificate on the EC2 instance. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html.
5. If you're using Ruby on Rails (as I am), the guide for installing the certificate on the instance is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-ruby.html.

So far so good: I don't have load balancing on my environment but - as you can see from the above - the docs say that it's not going to be essential.

Here's the problem, though. The instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-ruby.html expect me to provide the "private key contents" (or rather, a secure S3 link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html) in the body of the **.ebextensions/https-instance.config** file. Since ACM doesn't allow us to access the private key, I feel that I've been led on a wild goose chase and need to just set up load balancing on a new EB environment. Do you agree or am I missing something?

(I am not keen to get into load balancing at the moment as the project is still in development and I want to avoid the additional costs associated with it.)

Comment: Seems like the doco is assuming that you're generating your certificate yourself or getting it elsewhere if you're not using the load balancer and want end to end encryption. You might not want to get into LBs at the moment but wouldn't you prefer to get a firm grasp of how the load balancing works now rather than when you have to all of a sudden at release? It's 0.03 cents per hour as a low volume of data throughput and it can can be tied into your health checks, auto scaling, redirection in case of issues; basically it's a pretty important piece of the puzzle and it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah thanks, @Mokilok. You're right about "getting a grasp now". I will go down that path sooner rather than later unless someone else has a better suggestion in the next 48 hours.

Comment: As @Mokilok said, using load balancer will give you many advantages. As far as options go, consider using Let's Encrypt which gives free TLS certificates and you'll have the private key.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#letsencrypt

Comment: FWIW, I am now using LB for an extra US$20 or so each month, eventhough AWS doesn't force you to have more than one instance behind it.